# Code will be execute or stop if validation fail in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to know that what will be happen if validation fail in laravel, means that the rest of code will be execute or not. I have following code in store method

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'message' => 'required',
]);

return response()->json([
    'success' => 'Your email has been sent successfully.'
]);
```

I have checked with `$validator->fails())` but it does not return the error message which i added in the if statement.

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'There are some errors.'
    ]); 
}else{
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Your email has been sent successfully.'
    ]); 
}
```

Can anyone guide me about my question, i would like to appreciate. Thank You

Comment: are you working on API development or form with view (using blade) ?

Comment: @h44f33z I'm working with form with view (using blade)

Comment: your first code `$this->validate(...)` should work already, just need to output the errors in your blade view as mention by @Kris

Comment: You can use $validator->errors()->messages() or check Documentation about Laravel Validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: @JokoWandiro I tried as you instructed but its returning an error `Call to a member function fails() on a non-object`

Comment: put it in $validator->fails() conditional section

Comment: @JokoWandiro yes i did same `if ($validator->fails()) {...}`

Comment: @Mr.Developer If there's error $validator->fails() return true then script in conditional will be executed then you can use $validator->errors() or see documentation Laravel working with error messages https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No an exception will be thrown in your case upon validation fails. According to [laravel official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation):

> The validate method accepts an incoming HTTP request and a set of
>   validation rules. If the validation rules pass, your code will keep
>   executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be
>   thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back
>   to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect
>   response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for
>   AJAX requests.
>
> If you do not want to use the ValidatesRequests trait's validate
>   method, you may create a validator instance manually using the
>   Validator facade. The make method on the facade generates a new
>   validator

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($validator->fails())
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

then the client side:

```
<ul class="errors">
@foreach($errors->all() as $message)
  <li>{{ $message }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, can i add proper `if else` statement? `if($validator->fails()){..}else{..}`

Comment: I've not try the situation you described.

Comment: Its returning error `Call to a member function fails() on a non-object`